# How to create add value to array everytime i click submit button? in php (with session)

Tags: php

How to create add value to array everytime i click submit button? in php (with session)

Below are the working code, but in Javascript:

```
<html>
<body>


New array element:<br>
<input id="age" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<br>
<br>
<input 

type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">


<p id="demo">gg</p>

<script>
var fruits = [];
function myFunction()
{
    var newArray = document.getElementById("age").value;
    fruits.push(newArray);
    document.getElementById("age").value = "";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>

</body> </html>
```

Can someone plz convert the javascript above into php, with session and other?

Comment: Sorry mate, SO is not a place to get such help. You better go on freelancing website platforms where you can get JS and PHP dev. Such questions will always be discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to be able to submit your values through PHP, you have to use the `<form>` tag.

Try the below code:

```
<?php
    session_start() ;

    if (isset($_POST["firstname"])) {
        if ($_SESSION["array"] != "") {
            $_SESSION["array"] .= "," ;
        }

        $_SESSION["array"] .= $_POST["firstname"] ;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION["array"] = "" ;
    }

    $demo   = $_SESSION["array"] == "" ? "gg" : $_SESSION["array"] ;
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            New array element:<br>
            <input id="age" type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <p id="demo"><?php echo $demo ?></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

On click of Submit button send data to this php file :`index.php`

And here is the code for `index.php` file:

```
<?php
$sessionArray = $_SESSION['ageArray'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];
if(isset($age) && $age != ""){
    array_push($sessionArray,$age);
    $_SESSION['ageArray'] = $sessionArray;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['myArray'])){
          $_SESSION['myArray'] = array();
        }
        $_SESSION['myArray'][] = $_POST['firstname'];    
    }
?>
```