# How can I add values from a textbox to PHP with a custom key when a button is pressed without overwriting the existing array

Tags: php, html, arrays, session-state

I have a textbox within a HTML form. I'm trying to get PHP to add the value of that textbox to a PHP array as a key with a value of something else (for example, the word "bob"). The array should be persistent, it shouldnt be overwritten with new values each time, rather as the button is clicked further values should be added to the array.

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="dl-textarea" name="dl-textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add to array" name="submitText"/>
</form>
```

And the PHP I currently have is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["dl-textarea"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["array"] != ""){
        $_SESSION["array"] .= ",";
    }
    $_SESSION["array"] .= $_POST["dl-textarea"];
} else {
    $_SESSION["array"] = "";
}

$demo = $_SESSION["array"] == "" ? "gg" : $_SESSION["array"];
print_r($demo);
```

Which I picked up from the following StackOverflow answer.
[How to create add value to array everytime i click submit button? in php (with session)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647595/how-to-create-add-value-to-array-everytime-i-click-submit-button-in-php-with-s)
This inserts new values into the array with conventional keys (0, 1, 2, and so on). However, I would like to have some control over the keys so as to have the contents of the textarea as my key, and another value as my data (for example, if the textarea contained the word "text1", then when I click my button it would insert this into the array with "text1" being the key and something else as the data. And then afterwards, if the text area contained the word "text2", then clicking the button would add that to the array. So a final array might look like:  ['text1':'bob','text2':'bob','text3':bob'])

Comment: The PHP code really doesn't look like it would create new keys. It looks like it just appends to a string at the same "array" key. Anyway, if you want to use the value from the text area as the key, it's like this: `$_SESSION["array"][$_POST["dl-textarea"]] = $someValue;`

Comment: You're probably right, its just some PHP that I picked up from another answer that seemed to do the trick. It was the only code that seemed halfway close to what I wanted though.

Comment: Thanks for editing it for me :)